# dafny assert violated using sequence

Tags: recursion, assert, dafny

Here is the dafny code, the second assertion never pass, anyone can help me out? [enter link description here](http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/0KG4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dafny seems to have an easier time if you just use s[1..] instead of the equivalent s[1..|s|]. The updated version is at http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/1AQN.